# Convert JSON to HTML in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, typescript

I am trying to covert a JSON file to HTML using vanilla JavaScript. The way I approached it appears to be working but the code is not ideal.

What I am doing is checking to see if the value of the key is an object. If so, this is a new HTML tag. If not then this is a attribute for the tag.

The problem that I am having is that I don't know how to properly loop through an object and test these conditions without duplicating my code.

Can someone help me identify how I can better write this?

```
function createComponent(component, defaults, map) {


  Object.keys(defaults).forEach(function (level1) {
    if (typeof defaults[level1] === "object") {
      var tag = document.createElement(level1);
      Object.keys(defaults[level1]).forEach(function (level2) {
        if (typeof defaults[level1][level2] === "object") {
          tag.appendChild(document.createElement(level2));
            Object.keys(defaults[level1][level2]).forEach(function (level3) {
            if (typeof defaults[level1][level2][level3] === "object") {
                console.log(defaults[level1][level2][level3]);
               tag.appendChild(document.createElement(level3));
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
createComponent("textBox", textBoxDefaults, map);
```

Pseudo code:

Check defaults object, is there an object at this level? If so, create an HTML tag with the same Key name. Is there values that are not objects? If so, add attributes to the created tag using the key value pair. Stop diving deeper into the JSON when you don't find anymore objects.

### Sample JSON

```
 textbox: {
      id: 1,
      name: "Text Box",
      tmprops: {
        cur: 0,
        min: 5000,
        visible: true,
      },
      tmctxlst: {
        version: "2",
        txttmctx: {
          alwysshw: false,
          name: "default"
        }
      },
```

### Desired Output

```
 <textbox id="1" name="text box">
      <tmprops cur="0" min="5000" visible="true" />
      <tmctxlst version="2">
        <txttmctx alwysshow="false" name="default">
      </tmctxlst>
</textbox>
```

Comment: Sounds like you could do this with a recursive function... see if you can re-implement it using recursion. Also, if you could edit your post to include some example JSON and example desired output would be awesome!

Comment: Added sample JSON and Desired HTML output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a recursion to solve this,

Basically we take current object & it's key as string, then we traverse the object in `dfs` fashion & make applicable children, we're ending by returning the tag to the outer element.

```
window.onload = function () {
  console.log(solve(item.textbox, "textbox"));
}

const item = {
  textbox: {
    id: 1,
    name: "Text Box",
    tmprops: {
      cur: 0,
      min: 5000,
      visible: true,
    },
    tmctxlst: {
      version: "2",
      txttmctx: {
        alwysshw: false,
        name: "default"
      }
    },
  }
}

function solve(obj, tagName) {
  const tag = document.createElement(tagName);
  const currentKeys = Object.keys(obj)

  currentKeys.forEach((attribute => {
    if (typeof obj[attribute] === "object") {
      tag.appendChild(solve(obj[attribute], attribute))
    } else {
      tag.setAttribute(attribute, obj[attribute]);
    }
  }))
  return tag;
}
```

Output:

```
<textbox id=​"1" name=​"Text Box">​
    <tmprops cur=​"0" min=​"5000" visible=​"true">​</tmprops>
    <tmctxlst version=​"2">​
        <txttmctx alwysshw=​"false" name=​"default">​</txttmctx>
    </tmctxlst>
</textbox>
```

​

Comment: This is amazing, thank you very much. So simple and powerful.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the easiest way to avoid code duplication here is with recursion, and it can basically look like this:

```
function createObjectComponent(json) {
  const component = document.createElement("div");
  for(const entry of Object.entries(json)) {
    if(Array.isArray(value)) {
      component.appendChild(createArrayComponent(value));
    } else if(typeof value === "object") {
      component.appendChild(createObjectComponent(value));
    } else {
      component.appendChild(createSimpleValueComponent(value));
    }
  }
  return component
}
```

here's a working example, with some minor css, it includes your own example and also an example of an array handling component:

```js
const appDiv = document.getElementById('app');

const example1 = {
  foo: 1,
  bar: {
    id: 2,
    obj: {
      test: 2
    }
  },
  a: ["a", "b", 1, {
    a: 1
  }]
}

const example2 = {
  id: 1,
  name: "Text Box",
  tmprops: {
    cur: 0,
    min: 5000,
    visible: true,
  },
  tmctxlst: {
    version: "2",
    txttmctx: {
      alwysshw: false,
      name: "default"
    }
  }
}

appDiv.appendChild(createObjectComponent(example2));
appDiv.appendChild(createObjectComponent(example1));
appDiv.appendChild(createArrayComponent(example1.a));

function createObjectComponent(json) {
  const component = document.createElement("div");
  component.className = "obj-component";
  component.innerHTML += "{";

  for (const entry of Object.entries(json)) {
    component.appendChild(getComponentForEntry(entry));
  }

  component.innerHTML += "}";

  return component
}

function getComponentForEntry([key, value]) {
  const entryDiv = document.createElement("div");
  const keySpan = document.createElement("span");

  keySpan.className = "key-span";
  keySpan.innerText = key + ":";

  entryDiv.appendChild(keySpan);
  if (Array.isArray(value)) {
    entryDiv.appendChild(createArrayComponent(value));
  } else if (typeof value === "object") {
    entryDiv.appendChild(createObjectComponent(value));
  } else {
    entryDiv.appendChild(createSimpleValueComponent(value));
  }

  return entryDiv;
}

function createArrayComponent(array) {
  const list = document.createElement("ul");
  list.className = "array-component";
  list.innerHTML += "[";
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const item = array[i];
    const listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.appendChild(getComponentForEntry([i, item]))
    list.appendChild(listItem);
  }

  list.innerHTML += "]";

  return list;
}

function createSimpleValueComponent(value) {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerText = value;

  return span;
}
```

```css
#app {
  font-family: monospace;
}

div.obj-component {
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 4px 16px;
}

ul.array-component {
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 4px 16px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

span.key-span {
  padding-left: 16px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  color: blueviolet
}

span {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```